# How to create multiple coloured background in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data-visualization

I have a dataset that contains multiple groups and exp. conditions. (here represents as `group <- c("g1", "g2")` and `con <- c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2")`) I made a 3x3 plot matrix, and below is a part of one of the plots. a1 in the graph is just a derivative con of A1 and do not need to have a separate background than A1.

[image: example no background bar-chart]

What I want is give them different colour background and frames so they are more friendly to readers. (e.g. the following output but fill the entire plating area [colour filled background distinguishing condition A, B, while coloured border differentiates condition 1, 2]) How could I archive this in R?

[image: sample bar-chart with pseudo-background]

---- Update ----
As you commented, Here is a demo data that preserves the structure of the original data frame.

```
(sep = "    ")# I use csv in real data, 
# here is just for better presentation
group    animal_nr    region    con    gene1    gene2    gene3
g1    101    x    A1    10    15    100
g1    102    x    A1    12    15    110
g1    103    x    A1    9    16    90
g1    104    x    A1    11    14    105
g1    201    x    a1    10    15    100
g1    202    x    a1    12    16    110
g1    203    x    a1    9    16    90
g1    204    x    a1    11    14    105
g1    105    x    A2    -8    5    50
g1    106    x    A2    -9    5.5    52
g1    107    x    A2    -8    4    53
g1    108    x    A2    0    6    52.8
g1    205    x    a2    -8    5    50
g1    206    x    a2    -9    5.5    52
g1    207    x    a2    -8    4    53
g1    208    x    a2    0    6    52.8
g1    109    x    B1    2    15    29
g1    110    x    B1    3    15.5    35
g1    111    x    B1    1    16    33
g1    112    x    B1    1.1    14    30
g1    209    x    b1    2    15    29
g1    210    x    b1    3    15.5    35
g1    211    x    b1    1    16    33
g1    212    x    b1    1.1    14    30
g1    113    x    B2    -10    2    10
g1    114    x    B2    -8    3    11
g1    115    x    B2    -9    2    11.1
g1    116    x    B2    -11    4    12
g2    301    x    A1    10    15    100
g2    302    x    A1    12    15    110
g2    303    x    A1    9    16    90
g2    304    x    A1    11    14    105
g2    401    x    a1    10    15    100
g2    402    x    a1    12    16    110
g2    403    x    a1    9    16    90
g2    404    x    a1    11    14    105
g2    305    x    A2    -8    5    50
g2    306    x    A2    -9    5.5    52
g2    307    x    A2    -8    4    53
g2    308    x    A2    0    6    52.8
g2    405    x    a2    -8    5    50
g2    406    x    a2    -9    5.5    52
g2    407    x    a2    -8    4    53
g2    408    x    a2    0    6    52.8
```

Layout of real plot

```
grid(r = 3, n = 3)
gene/region    x    y    z
gene1
gene2
gene3
```

Comment: It also welcome to give suggestions to use another R package or custom functions!! A lot of thanks for any advice

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: @stefan yes I just added a demo (fake) data frame thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you could add some background rectangles using `geom_rect`. which however requires some data wrangling to get the `xmin` and `xmax` values. Basically this involves setting up a dataframe and converting your categories to numeric positions. Also at this stage we also add some columns which could be mapped on `fill` and `color` to achieve your desired result. Note that I slightly reduced the rect size to `width_rect = .98` to prevent the outlines from overlapping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Prep data for column and errorbars
df_sum <- df |> 
  group_by(group, con) |> 
  summarise(across(gene3, .fns = list(mean = mean, sd = sd)))

# Set up dataframe for background rectangles
width_rect <- .98
rects <- data.frame(
  con = factor(unique(df$con))
)
rects <- rects |> 
  mutate(con_num = as.numeric(con), 
         con_group = toupper(con)) |> 
  group_by(con_group) |> 
  summarise(xmin = min(con_num) - width_rect / 2, 
            xmax = max(con_num) + width_rect / 2) |> 
  mutate(fill = substr(con_group, 1, 1), 
         color = substr(con_group, 2, 2))

pd <- position_dodge(width = .9, preserve = "single")

ggplot(df_sum, aes(con, gene3_mean, fill = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, fill = fill, color = color, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            data = rects, inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 1, alpha = .3) +
  geom_col(position = pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gene3_mean - 1.96 * gene3_sd, 
                    ymax = gene3_mean + 1.96 * gene3_sd), 
                width = .1, position = pd) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Instead of using `substr` you could of course use an `ifelse` or ... to assign the categories to fill and color:

```
rects <- rects |> 
  ...
  mutate(fill = ifelse(con_group %in% c("A1", "A2"), "A", "B"), 
         color = ifelse(con_group %in% c("A1", "B1"), "1", "2"))
```

Comment: I saw you use the first or the second letter in constructing the rects, But my real grouping is not one-letter+1dig coding but the letter or digit here `c('A', 'B') || c(1, 2)` would be 1 or 2 dig code e.g. `('A', 'AB') || c('C', 'CD')` and `A` vs `a` in real data is `A` vs `prefix-A`. My question is how should I reflect this?

Comment: There is of course no need to use `substr`. You could always use an `ifelse` or `case_when` in more general cases. See my edit.

Comment: So I can also use nested `if` `else`?

Comment: with ifelse I still get an error: `prefix-A/1`, `prefix-AB/1`, `prefix-A/11` etc has value `fill = AB colour = 11` (every condition with `prefix-`) while the rest has value `fill = A colour = 1`

Comment: I think I get what you meant in your update. Correct me if I misunderstood. So the vector you use to filter (with `%in%`) contains only the value that matches the first type of condition (thus `A` or `a`) and you are calling them in the `fill` as `A` and what doesn't matches as `B`, right?

Comment: I'm almost there, but geom_rect produce 2 rectangle border instead of one as showing in your demo, I used you code except I did pass `toupper()` because in real data it was not differentiate by capitalisation but by a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example with dummy data and using `geom_rec` you can select that part of the background that you want to fill with some color, changing `xmin` and `xmax`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  name=letters[1:5],
  value=sample(seq(4,15),5),
  sd=c(1,0.2,3,2,4)
)

# Plot
ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar( aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=0.7) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=0.25,xmax=1.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="lightgreen", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=1.25,xmax=2.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="red", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=2.25,xmax=3.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="lightblue", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=3.25,xmax=4.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="yellow", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=name, ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), 
                width=0.4, colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1.3)
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: But in your demo the width of each colour background is not matching the bar right?

Comment: And if I want to make this rectangles in the background (instead of overlaying the actual bar) do I just need to put the bar chart function to the bottom? like this `ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar( aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=0.7) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=1.25,xmax=2.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="red", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=2.25,xmax=3.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="lightblue", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=0.25,xmax=1.25,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),
            fill="lightgreen", alpha=0.1)`